# Using a DB File to run Tests on Azure Devops

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to create a DB File on the Azure Devops pipeline using one of the tasks?

My line of thought is Create a localdb on the agent (Using VS) and run the unit tests (SSDT) on that DB file like I do with VS. I can create db file Tools>connect db> Sql server db file and putting in a name. I can connect to it and run the tests. It seems like I cant do this on Azure devops pipeline.

I know the preferred way is to allocate an Azure SQL server and run the tests against those but the DB is very small and if i can run those against the db file it seems like a better idea.

Comment: Or you use an inmemory db for tests ?

Comment: I prefer to not create someone on azure that would take a pricing tier. Hence, I wanted to create a db file on the agent so i can run tests on it since it is a small.

Comment: Or is there a good reason not to do what I am doing?

Comment: Inmemory databases are just created in memory as the name implies. It is a feature in entity framework for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically I found a way to do it all on the agent. However, the agent localdb has to be updated if you are using newer syntax.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: '**/Output/*.dacpac'
    flattenFolders: true
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |      
      sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB
      sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB

      #import SqlServer module
      Import-Module -Name "SqlServer"

      # create variable with SQL to execute
      $sql = "
      CREATE DATABASE [MyDatabase]
        CONTAINMENT = NONE
        ON  PRIMARY
        ( NAME = N'MyDatabase', FILENAME = N'd:\a\1\s\testing.Data\test\bin\Output\MyDatabase.mdf' , SIZE = 1048576KB , FILEGROWTH = 262144KB )
        LOG ON
        ( NAME = N'MyDatabase_log', FILENAME = N'd:\a\1\s\testing.Data\test\bin\Output\MyDatabase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 524288KB , FILEGROWTH = 131072KB )
      GO

      USE [master]
      GO
      ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE WITH NO_WAIT
      GO

      ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[MyDatabase] TO [sa]
      GO "
      Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -database master -Query $sql

- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  inputs:
    TaskType: 'dacpac'
    DacpacFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.dacpac'
    TargetMethod: 'connectionString'
    ConnectionString: 'Data Source=(localdb)\.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;'
```

With this you can attach a created .mdf file that was generate to your localdb and publish your dacpac to it. Then if you want to run your tests, you can do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Using a DB File to run Tests on Azure Devops

As workaround, you could try to check-in the LocalDb files (mdf and ldf), copy the files to output and change the connection string to use the current execution path:

[image]

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer($”Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Contacts;AttachDbFilename={AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Core\\IntegrationTests\\Contacts.mdf;Integrated Security=True”);
}
```

You could check the document [Integration Testing with SQL LocalDb on your build server](https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2018/09/18/integration-testing-with-sql-localdb-on-your-build-server/) for some details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I found a way to do it on the hosted agent and ill reply here