# LocalDb "read-only" error after switching pipeline from windows-2019 to windows-2022

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our pipeline mounts some SQL Server `.mdf` files as LocalDBs in order to run some tests.

After switching the pipeline from windows-2019 to windows-2022, our tests requiring the DB generate the following errors:

> Database 'xxxxxxxxxxx' cannot be upgraded because it is read-only, has read-only files or the user does not have permissions to modify some of the files. Make the database or files writeable, and rerun recovery

The `.mdf` files are not read-only databases and mount fine locally.

I have tried recursively turning off the read-only flags on the directory in case the 2022 version of Windows is setting the build directories with different defaults and that has not helped. Any suggestions for why this might have happened / a fix?

Comment: Are you using the self-hosted agent? If so, are you using the same account as the agent service account in windows-2019 and windows-2022? It seems to be a service account permission issue.

Comment: Not a self hosted agent, using the DevOps hosted ones :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue in one of my pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Pipeline accesses file via service account, we should check the service account permission and ensure it has enough permission.

If you are using MS hosted agent, it accesses the file via this account `test Build Service(Org name)`, we need open project settings->Repositories->select the repo and check the service account `test Build Service ({Org name})` permission, and also check the Pipeline->Settings

If you are using self-hosted agent and access local file, you should check the file permission. Just make sure the service account has the writable permission to the files.

Select the local file->Properties->Security, the service account name should be Administrators (Agent service name\Administrators) or Users (Agent service name\Users who has the correct permissions granted).

Just try to set file permissions of the `.mdf` to writable for `BUILTIN\Users` or service account.

Comment: Hi Andy, for the MS Hosted agent, what should those permissions be? I can't seem to find anything in those areas related to write access to a file.

Comment: Just check the service account permissions, there isn't a writable permission as local windows. However, please make sure the service account has the manage permission on the repo.

Comment: Have confirmed it has this permission and still get the error.

Comment: May I know how you mount the .mdf as a local db in pipeline? Just found a [similar ticket here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285909/using-a-db-file-to-run-tests-on-azure-devops) for your reference, please check if that helps.